# Optimizing Media Player and Slider in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I am making a WPF application that is similar to a video player. There is a MediaElement for the video, and a slider that is bound to the video. I also want the current timestamp to appear.

```
public MainWindow()   
{
     InitializeComponent();

     DataContext = VideoViewModel;
     ViewModel1.video_timestamp = "00:00:00:00";

     DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();      
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);  
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;                       
        timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if ((VideoElement.Source != null) && (VideoElement.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)) 
      {
          Slider1.Minimum = 0;
          Slider1.Maximum = VideoElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
          Slider1.Value = VideoElement.Position.TotalMilliseconds;
       }
}

private void VidSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    ViewModel1.video_timestamp = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Slider1.Value).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:ff");
    VideoElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Slider1.Value); 
    DataContext = ViewModel1;
}
```

VidSlider_ValueChanged should update the textbox that shows the current video timestamp. So when a video is playing, this function is called every tick. When the user drags the thumb, this function is also called. The problem is that this **seems to slow the application down especially when the video is long** and when the user keeps on dragging the thumb quickly.

I am thinking about doing some Threading but I'm at a loss with the syntax since this some kind of click event(?) in XAML. Can I have some suggestions?

PS. I should display in milliseconds because this data will be used for another application later on.

Comment: previously (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74547586/application-is-slow-because-of-timer-tick-wpf-c) you claimed it is timer which causes lag

Comment: *"especially when the video is long"* - This indicates that your operation triggers the re-evaluation of the complete video or sort of. This is probably a buffering issue. It could make sense to pause the video until the user is done with moving the slider. Like a deferred seek and also ensure that `MediaElement.ScrubbingEnabled` is set to `false`. Threading won't help you with this. The best is to wait for drag completion before seeking: either find the underlying Thumb and handle the Thumb.DragCompleted event or listen to a mouse up event.

Comment: Alternatively, since you know the slider resolution you are able to convert the slider's drag delta into a range or seek interval. Like you could seek every 5s. In other words, let the user skip *n* seconds to trigger a seek in order to give a raw preview. Then complete the seek on Thumb.DragCompleted.

Comment: @BionicCode, thank you for your suggestions. I used Thumb.DragStarted() and Thumb.DragCompleted() to Pause and Play the video respectively. The desired behavior is still there but the response had improved immensely. Thank you so much again!